PromQL number of Pod restarts last hour
Looking to return the number of Pod restarts per Namespace in the last hour (or 24 hours).
Working in an Openshift Kubernetes environment with Grafana for development and display.
Using kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total command. Trying to get the results needed using various combinations of sum by, count by, rate, increase.
I'm getting global totals, or fractional numbers, or errors about instant vector and expecting a range vector.
I'd like to return the number (literal integer whole number) of Pod restarts by Namespace in the last hour.
Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks!
Things tried:
sum by (namespace) (kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total) > 0 

count by (namespace) rate(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total[60m] 

sum by (namespace)(increase(kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason[1h]))

Expecting the number of Pod restarts in the last hour by Namespace.

For what you’re trying to achieve you can use the increase() function. This function is appropriate because it calculates the increase in a counter value over a specified time period. The kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total metric is a counter, making increase() suitable.
To get the number of Pod restarts per namespace use the following query:
sum by (namespace)(increase(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total[1h]))

This query will calculate and sum up the increase in the kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total metric over the last hour, grouped by each namespace.
